# Can't access some pages without index.php on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ive just uploaded to the server and have encountered the problem that i can only see my home page unless i add www.site.com/index.php/ **(index.php)** after the url. Is this a frequent error for laravel and what is the fix?

Comment: Means you haven't read the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#web-server-configuration

Comment: Maybe i have and maybe it still doesn't work

Comment: If you can't access it without the `index.php`, you didn't get the pretty URL configuration right. Show us that config.

Comment: Where should my .htaccess be in root or public?

Comment: It should go in the same file as the index.php, typically `public` (although some folks move it around).

Answer (score -1):

Laravel not call url *.php , *.html
you can call index.blade.php from route
routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```